# How can I create a custom vertical stack scroll for flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am trying to achieve this *vertical stack scroll* or *vertical stack ListView* (if there is a different term used for this kind of scrolls, please share it) for a web app, but I haven't found any package that does anything close to it

[image]

Is there some built in widget or a package that can help me achieve this?

Comment: It seems that [swipable_stack](https://pub.dev/packages/swipable_stack) could offer what you need.

Comment: It's not specifically what I want, the closest I found the carousel_slider, but I can't manage to stack/overlap them like in the picture

Comment: But you can check the code of the package and check how the interactions are implemented. Later, you can implement the UI based on your needs. It may not be the _exact_ package available, but you can check how specific interactions are implemented and adapt them.